# Place charters in a grid when pressing a certain character

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-interface

I'm trying to make a grid game which will allow the user to move around a grid and collect items. I've only made the grid, being able to fill in the grid when clicking a square and a few buttons.

I'm trying to implement that if a user clicks on a certain tile and then presses a certain character key, then that character will appear in the tile.

I've already made a switch case to alert a user if they input a certain tile but I don't know how to implement it so it will input the character key in the tile.

You may need to download this image for the grid to show but the error still demonstrates itself without it. 
[image]

```js
    var s ={
         rows: 10,
         cols: 10,
         width: 40,
         height: 40,


         };

         document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 49: case 50: case 51: case 52: case 53: case 54: case 55: case 56: case 57:
            alert('number');
            break;
        case 75:
            alert('k');
            break;
        case 79:
            alert('o');
            break;
        case 85:
            alert('u');
            break;
        case 65:
            alert('a');
            break;
        case 68:
            alert('d');
            break;
        case 87:
            alert('w');
            break;
        case 88:
            alert('x');
            break;
    }
};


         var c;


         window.onload = function(){
         var canvas = document.getElementById("gCanvas");
         c = canvas.getContext("2d");

         init();
         } 




         var mX;
         var mY;
         var clickedX;
         var clickedY;

         window.onclick = function(e){



         c.strokeStyle = "black";



         c.fillRect(Math.floor(e.offsetX/40)*40, 
                            Math.floor(e.offsetY/40)*40,
                            40, 40);

         mX = e.pageX;
         mY = e.pageY;

         if(Math.floor(mX/s.width) < s.cols && Math.floor(mY/s.height) < s.rows){
         clickedX = Math.floor(mX/s.width);
         clickedY = Math.floor(mY/s.height);

         console.log(clickedX + "," + clickedY);


         }

         }









         var box;

         box = new Image();
         box.src = "box.png";


         function init(){


         drawCanvas();

         }

         function drawCanvas(){

         c.clearRect(0,0,400,400);

         for(var i=0; i<s.rows; i++){
         for(var n=0; n<s.cols; n++){
         var x = n*s.width;
         var y = i*s.height;
         c.drawImage(box, x, y);
         }
         }
         }

         function myFunction() {
             document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "game started";
    event.stopPropagation();
         }

         function test() {
             alert('game ended');
    event.stopPropagation();
         }


 function refreshGame() {
             alert('game refresh');
    event.stopPropagation();
         }

  

function refresh() {

alert('game refresh');

    setTimeout(function () {
        location.reload()
    }, 100);
 event.stopPropagation();
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

h1 {
    color: navy;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.active{
    background:#357EBD;
    color:#FFF
}
```

```html
   <body>
      <h1>grid game</h1>


   </body>
   
      
      <style>
         body{
         margin:0;
         }
         h1 {
         text-align: center;
         }
      </style>
      
      
 
   <body>
      <div id = "controls">
      </div>
      <div id ="gameCanvas">
         <canvas id ="gCanvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
      </div>
      <body>

         <button class="button" onclick="myFunction()">Start game</button>
         <p id="demo"></p>
         
   
   <input type="submit" value="Refresh game" data-wrapper-class="custom-btn" data-corners="false" id="submit" onclick="refresh()">

         <button class="button" onclick="test()">end game</button>
   </body>
   </body>
```

Comment: I think you should to start from the basics. This HTML code is wrong, how many "body" tag you have in this page ?? Start reading here, easy and clear: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp and here https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_basic.asp and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I spotted it out! What is happening is the a var canvas is created when the window is loaded due to this that var has its origin inside the function. Hence, to solve the issue all you need to do is specify the var canvas as well as var c out of the `window.onload = function(){}`